# How to use and extend an HTML template in other HTML pages in Truffle?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, truffle

In Django, Spring, and other frameworks, you can define a base HTML template which can be imported and included in other HTML pages instead of manually copying the HTML snippets.

What is the standard procedure for doing the same in Truffle and web3js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Truffle is not a web framework and does not give you tools to extend HTML templates. In fact, it really does not care HTML at all. So your question really does not have a point.

Instead you should ask "How do I integrate smart contracts and web3 wallets to by website".

You can use whatever template framework you are familiar with to generate the pages. Then you integrate Web3 on these pages using web3.js JavaScript library.

I think the best starting point for you is an example here how to do wallet actions with Web3modal library in plain HTML and vanilla JavaScript:

https://github.com/Web3Modal/web3modal-vanilla-js-example